# How to seperate and graph transaction/thread group results seperately

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

new to jmeter and i wanted to see if it was possible to separate results on a graph by per request (in this case i am testing apis)

I want to see how many transactions per api request and to see if they're being called at the same time to see if i am overloading my system with requests that are coming in parallel(submitting request within one another). I want to see if  the correct pacing time is being utilized and they're spread out

i look at TPS in html dashboard but it only shows granularity of 1 minute and i think i would have a better idea if it was in seconds

i apologize if it doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

With regards to "separating" transactions - just give them different names and you will get "separate" charts

[image]

Report granularity can be configured via `jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity` property.

So if you launch the above test plan in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(API 1|API 2)(-success|-failure)?$" -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

You will get separate charts and 1 second granularity, hopefully it's something you're looking for.

[image]

More information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)